# Understanding kmeans clustering in r

Tags: r, k-means

Below code (minus my questions) generates this graph :

[image]

I have marked 4 areas of confusion with "->"

```
> m <- matrix(c(1,1,1) , ncol=3)
> 
> x <- rbind(matrix(c(1,0,1) , ncol=3),
+            matrix(c(1,1,1) , ncol=3),
+            matrix(c(1,1,0) , ncol=3),
+            matrix(c(0,1,1) , ncol=3),
+            matrix(c(0,0,1) , ncol=3),
+            matrix(c(0,0,0) , ncol=3),
+            matrix(c(1,1,1) , ncol=3),
+            matrix(c(1,1,1) , ncol=3),
+            matrix(c(1,1,0) , ncol=3),
+            matrix(c(1,0,0) , ncol=3),
+            matrix(c(0,0,1) , ncol=3),
+            matrix(c(0,0,0) , ncol=3),
+            matrix(c(0,0,1) , ncol=3),
+            matrix(c(0,1,1) , ncol=3),
+            matrix(c(1,0,1) , ncol=3),
+            matrix(c(0,1,0) , ncol=3))
> colnames(x) <- c("google", "stackoverflow", "tester")
> (cl <- kmeans(x, 3))

K-means clustering with 3 clusters of sizes 3, 10, 3
-> Where are sizes 3, 10 3 appearing  ?

Cluster means:
     google stackoverflow tester
1 0.6666667           1.0      0
2 0.5000000           0.5      1
3 0.3333333           0.0      0

-> There are three clusters, but what does each number signify ?

Clustering vector:
 [1] 2 2 1 2 2 3 2 2 1 3 2 3 2 2 2 1

-> This looks to be created by summing the values of each matrix but seems to be unordered as second element in this vector is '2' but second element in 'x' is matrix(c(1,1,1) , ncol=3) which is '3'

Within cluster sum of squares by cluster:
[1] 0.6666667 5.0000000 0.6666667
 (between_SS / total_SS =  46.1 %)

-> what are between_SS & total_SS ?

Available components:

[1] "cluster"      "centers"      "totss"        "withinss"     "tot.withinss"
[6] "betweenss"    "size"        
> plot(x, col = cl$cluster)
> points(cl$centers, col = 1:5, pch = 8, cex = 2)
>
```

Can provide answers to these questions as from reading the implementation of this algorithm (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-means_clustering) I fail to see how r is computing these values

Comment: I think you'd do better asking this over on CrossValidated. There's no programming question here; your issues are about understanding the output.

Comment: re "on hold": OP asks 4 specific questions which are stated in the code. He directs your attention to these questions immediately prior to the code. I'm not sure where the "unclear what you're asking" confusions is. It seemed pretty clear to me.

Comment: @DavidMarx because SO is supposed to be a site for _programming questions_, not statistics questions, and there is no programming question to be found. SO can be a bit passive-aggressive at times, but this question is pretty obviously off-topic here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**1. What does the cluster sizes mean?**

You provided 16 records and told kmeans to find 3 clusters. It clustered those 16 records into 3 groups of A: 3 records, B: 10 records and C: 3 records.

**2. What are the cluster means?**

These numbers signify the location in N-Dimensional space of the centroid (the "mean") of each cluster. You have three clusters, so you have three means. You have three dimensions ("google", "stackoverflow", "tester") so you get a value in each dimension. Reading the numbers across the row gives the location of a single centroid.

**3. What is the Clustering vector?**

This is the cluster label the algorithm is giving each record you passed the algorithm. Remember how earlier I said there were 3 clusters of size 3, 10, and 3? These clusters are labeled as 1, 2 and 3, and the algorithm stores the cluster label for each record in this vector. Here, you can see that there are 3 "1"s, 10 "2"s, and 3 "3"s. Does that make sense?

**4. What are between_SS & total_SS?**

This is notation generally used in ANOVA. You might find this helpful: http://www-ist.massey.ac.nz/dstirlin/CAST/CAST/HrandBlock/randBlock7.html

Comment: thanks, im still confused about this : "Within cluster sum of squares by cluster:
[1] 0.6666667 5.0000000 0.6666667" how are these three values computed, do they correspond to the Euclidean distance between each centroid ?

Comment: Sort of. The within cluster sum of squares for a single cluster is the SS-residuals (i.e. MSE) from each record in the cluster to the centroid. The "within cluster sum of squares" is the sum of this MSE calculation across all of the clusters. This values is what k-means aims to minimize: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-means_clustering#Description.

Comment: Should there not be more points in this graph, I mean there are 16 points of which 8 are unique, but the graph is just displaying points at the four corners at positions (1,0) & (1,1), is this because this is in 3 dminensional space so some of the points are hidden ? If im going off topic I can raise a new question.

Comment: The plot you posted isn't in three-dimensional space, it's only in two dimensional space. Look at the axes: it's plotting google vs. stackoverflow. The points are stacking on top of each other. Try this instead: `pairs(jitter(x), col = cl$cluster)`. You should see clear separation between the google/stackoverflow dimensions, but overlap when you consider the tester dimension.